# Where can aircraft carriers carry out air operations?

Tags: military, regulations, aircraft-carrier

I'm interested in any military or civil **airspace regulations** about where aircraft carriers are allowed to launch and retrieve aircraft.

For example, are fixed wing aircraft allowed to take off from an aircraft carrier while it is docked in port?

I would imagine (though could be wrong) land-based ATC and airspace conflicts have to be managed, amongst other issues.

Comment: You generally want to be underway when launching fixed-wing aircraft so that you get the most airspeed possible for take-off.

Comment: @SMSvonderTann that makes sense. I was wondering if there's any regulations that effect where it can they can take off though.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast nice! How do they coordinate though?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what permissions are required (guessing a fair bit of paperwork, involving not only the FAA but also port authorities), but taking off in port (in this case, a museum ship) has been done.  The USS Midway was stationary, looks like minimal wind, but on the other hand an acrobatic plane with lots of power. ([Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V6nQw0a2Yq4))

Comment: Nice video! Do you have any other information on this? It doesn't look like they used the normal ship ATC.

Comment: @Notts90 This was probably conducted under an airshow TFR, which means that they closed the airspace around the vessel specifically for this demonstration. In that case the pilot only needed to coordinate with somebody running the airshow.

Comment: I don't have any more information, but suspect the airshow TFR is probably correct.

Comment: The real question is how did they get the plane on the deck in the first place. ;)

Comment: @FreeMan Since they are competition aircraft they don't typically fly them cross-country. The wings and tail are easily removed and they are put into covered trailers or transport pallets. You can see how it is done [on the Red Bull Air Race website](http://www.redbullairrace.com/en_US/article/transporting-world-championship) or [Aviation Buzz Word](http://aviationbuzzword.com/heres-what-it-takes-to-transport-an-entire-air-race-across-the-world/). It was probably lifted onto the deck with a crane.

Comment: @RonBeyer - I assumed it was hoisted on deck, but it's much more fun to think of it landing there on its own! After all, there are all those Alaska bush pilots who could get in a full day's worth of touch-n-go practice on one pass down the deck... :)

Comment: @Freeman *how did they get the plane on the deck in the first place.* The same way they got an SR-71 onto the Intrepid. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Most carrier operations are carried out beyond the 12 nautical mile boundary in international waters.  This means international airspace as well, so Class A, B, etc. categories don't apply.

For training exercises conducted off the US coastline they operate in the off-shore Warning areas depicted in aviation charts.

When deployed it's much the same, crews are briefed on local airspace restrictions before each flight.

Fixed wing flight operations are never conducted while tied up in port for reasons that have nothing to do with civil airspace.